# how receive arraylist in fragment

Tags: android, arraylist

I need to know how to get array list using Bundle in fragment , in the [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment) I have seen they are using ints or strings. how to get fragments ? In my activity it was working good getting the arraylist

my updated code

```
public class SingleViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ImageView   imageView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_view);


        ArrayList<Listitem> personArrayList = new ArrayList<Listitem>();
// add some ListItem's...
        DemoObjectFragment f = DemoObjectFragment.newInstance(personArrayList);


        ViewPager    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.funnyimage);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        Log.d("s","singleview");
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter);


/*
        DemoCollectionPagerAdapter      mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter =      new DemoCollectionPagerAdapter( getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
           imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.funnyimage);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        Log.d("s","singleview");
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter);*/

    /*  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // During initial setup, plug in the details fragment.
            MyFragment myrag = new MyFragment();
            myrag.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, myrag).commit();
        }
*/
    }
```

---

```
        // Since this is an object collection, use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter,
        // and NOT a FragmentPagerAdapter.

        public class DemoCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
            public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "Person_List";

            public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Listitem> personArrayList)
            {
                super(fm);
                Log.d("s","adapterview");
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int i) {

                Fragment fragment = new DemoObjectFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                // Our object is just an integer :-P
                args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_PERSON_LIST, i + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 100;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
            }
        }
```

---

```
// Instances of this class are fragments representing a single
// object in our collection.
public class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PERSON_LIST = "Person_List";

    private ArrayList<Listitem> items;

    public  DemoObjectFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Listitem> items) {
        DemoObjectFragment f = new DemoObjectFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArrayList(ARG_PERSON_LIST, items);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args.containsKey(ARG_PERSON_LIST)) {
            // UNTESTED: probably will need to cast this
            this.items = args.getParcelableArrayList(ARG_PERSON_LIST);
        } else { // avoid the NullPointerException later by initializing the list
            this.items = new ArrayList<Listitem>();
        }
        // use this.items as you wish, but it will be empty if you didn't set the Bundle argument correctly
    }
}
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                                     ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // The last two arguments ensure LayoutParams are inflated
                // properly.

                View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.fragment_collection_object, container, false);
              //  Bundle args = getArguments();
             //   ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)));
                Bundle args= new Bundle();



                ArrayList<Listitem> personArrayList = args.getParcelableArrayList("Person_List");
                System.out.print(personArrayList);

                System.out.print("here1");

                if (personArrayList != null && !personArrayList.isEmpty()) {
                    for (Listitem person : personArrayList) {
                        Picasso.
                                with(getActivity()).
                                load(person.url)
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                                .fit()
                                .noFade()
                                .into(imageView);
                        Log.i("PersonsActivity",String.valueOf(person.url));
                    }
                }
                return rootView;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

I have 2 errors now :
[image]

for newInstance as I mentioned before I cannot refer to not static .

and I am getting error now for picasso

[image]

edit 3 [image]

Comment: You are using `putSerializable(String key, Serializable value)`. You need to use `putParcelableArrayList(String, key, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)`.

Comment: @JaredRummler do you have an example for `putParcelableArrayList` so I can apply it in my code ?

Comment: Does your `Listitem` class implement `Parcelable`? If so, it's as simple as `bundle.putParcelableArrayList("your_key", yourList)`

Comment: @JaredRummler please check is my fragment class correct in this way , check my edit please

Comment: You need to initialize the ArrayList, put the ArrayList in a bundle and add that bundle to your fragment in `newInstance`

Comment: @JaredRummler I got error for personArrayList , please check my edit and can you tell me where I did wrong ?

Comment: It says what you did wrong in the comment. You need to initialize personArrayList.

Comment: @JaredRummler one more question please where should I declare mcontext ?  if declare above in the fragment , its not reading `with(mcontext).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good start for what you are looking for and assumes you have correctly implemented `Parcelable` for the `ListItem` class.

**Somewhere in your Activity**

```
ArrayList<ListItem> personArrayList = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
// add some ListItem's...
DemoObjectFragment f = DemoObjectFragment.newInstance(personArrayList);
```

**From the top of your Fragment class** (note: it is not a `static class`)

```
public class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PERSON_LIST = "Person_List";

    private ArrayList<ListItem> items;

    public static DemoObjectFragment newInstance(ArrayList<ListItem> items) {
        DemoObjectFragment f = new DemoObjectFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArrayList(ARG_PERSON_LIST, items);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
   }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args.containsKey(ARG_PERSON_LIST)) {
            // UNTESTED: probably will need to cast this
            this.items = args.getParcelableArrayList(ARG_PERSON_LIST);
        } else { // avoid the NullPointerException later by initializing the list
            this.items = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
        }
        /*
        * use this.items as you wish, but 
        * it will be empty if you didn't set the 
        * Bundle argument correctly
        */
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_collection_object, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Log.i("DemoObjectFragment", "Inside onCreateView");

        if (this.items.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i("DemoObjectFragment", "Warning: There are no items!");
        }

        if (this.items != null) {
            for (Listitem person : items) {
                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(person.url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                    .fit()
                    .noFade()
                    .into(imageView);
                Log.i("DemoObjectFragment", "Person URL: " + String.valueOf(person.url));
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("DemoObjectFragment", "Oh no! items is null!");
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help its night over here so ill test it tomorow and ill tell us if it worked

Comment: i have an error can you please check my  edit please

Comment: Are you also new to Java? Initialize the ArrayList... `ArrayList<Listitem> personArrayList = new ArrayList<Listitem>();`. **OR** pass it in as a parameter to `newInstance()` as I have shown

Comment: Actually, just look at the parameters to `newInstance`. What are they? `(int imageResourceId, int numberSelected)`... There is no `ArrayList<Listitem>` there, right? **That** is your error.

Comment: I have initliazed already the personarraylist , its shown in my edit. beside when I removed the static from the fragment I got an error   in newInstance      `DemoObjectFragment f = DemoObjectFragment.newInstance(personArrayList);` Non static method can be refrenced .. can you help me in them ?

Comment: i have updated my code i did some modiication yesterday

Comment: Here is what you have `public Fragment newInstance(Context context,ArrayList<Listitem> personArrayList)`. **1)** That method is not `static` as it should be. Look at my answer. **2)** You don't need the `Context` parameter, you can just call `getActivity()` from within the Fragment class **3)** You are welcome to have that method return `Fragment`, but it makes more sense for it to return `DemoObjectFragment` as my answer has shown

Comment: I did what you said ..I still have 2 errors , please check my update question , I really appreaciate your help, I still need to fix this issue so I can send my project. thanks

Comment: For your first error. Look carefully at number 1 I mentioned above. For the second error, that is definitely [a valid method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: when i added it like this i get error on static   public static DemoObjectFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Listitem> items) and error says inner classes cannot have static declaration .. want screenshot ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100504/discussion-between-cricket-007-and-moudiz).

Comment: @Moudiz - I'm actually busy today, sorry. I think you got pretty far yesterday and should be able to make a new post with any additional errors/questions you have.

Comment: hi man I asked a new question related to the code we where working on it can you check it please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799975/a-fragment-is-not-being-accessed-from-from-viewpageradapter

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the fragment has no way of knowing what `personArrayList` you are referring to. Usually you pass the list as an extra argument in the newInstance method (step 1), save it in the bundle (step 2) and then retrieve it from the bundle in onCreate (step 3).

To fix you code you would have to either initialize the list with a `new ArrayList()`, but it would be empty in that case, or do as I said above (you're just missing step 1, so you're almost done).

Comment: I did what jared told me but i am facng another issue , how to declare the context to add it in picasso ? If u check my code above in the part where i add picasso , where should i seclare the context ? In the fragment create view or where

Comment: You don't need to declare a new context, the hosting activity is a valid context in Android. Just call getActivity() to get one.

Comment: @Moudiz - If you error is in reference to the context for Picasso, you can create a question specifically for that, otherwise flower_green is correct here, you simply need to do `getActivity()` to get the `Context` within the `Fragment`

Comment: Yes flower green helped here i add getactivity